# R, using dplyr::mutate with ifelse containing a grepl() gives unexpected result

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, grepl

What is wrong with this ifelse statement.

```
df <- data.frame(var1=c('ABC','CAB', 'AB'))
dplyr::mutate(df, var2=ifelse(grepl('^AB',var1), 'AB-starter', var1))
```

Gives

```
  var1       var2
1  ABC AB-starter
2  CAB          3
3   AB AB-starter
```

I wanted (using mutate and a ifelse statement) the value of var1 in second element of var2 (that is when 'var1' does not start with "AB"):

```
  var1       var2
1  ABC AB-starter
2  CAB        CAB
3   AB AB-starter
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As 'var1' is a `factor`, it gets coerced to integer value within `ifelse`.  We can avoid it by `as.character`

```
mutate(df, var2=ifelse(grepl('^AB',var1), 'AB-starter', as.character(var1)))
```

or when creating the `data.frame`, use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

Comment: Ah! I thought I already tested that possibility (stringsAsFactors=F) but I had the wrong variabel name in that line. It turns out that after a melt operation (in my real data) the factor came back.